# Compute $I=\int_0^2(3x^2-3x+1)\cos(x^3-3x^2+4x-2)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

If the value of $I = \int\limits_0^2 {\left( {3{x^2} - 3x + 1} \right)\cos \left( {{x^3} - 3{x^2} + 4x - 2} \right)dx} $ can be expressed as $p(\sin q)$ , where $p,q\in \mathbb N$, then $p+q-1=$?

My approach is as follow ${x^3} - 3{x^2} + 4x - 2 = {x^3} - {x^2} - 2\left( {{x^2} - 2x + 2} \right) \Rightarrow {x^3} - 3{x^2} + 4x - 2 = {x^2}\left( {x - 1} \right) - 2{\left( {x - 1} \right)^2}$

${x^3} - 3{x^2} + 4x - 2 = \left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {{x^2} - 2\left( {x - 1} \right)} \right) \Rightarrow {x^3} - 3{x^2} + 4x - 2 = \left( {x - 1} \right)\underbrace {\left( {{x^2} - 2x + 2} \right)}_{ > 0}$

Unable to proceed as cannot find the substitution of ${x^3} - 3{x^2} + 4x - 2$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $y=x-1$, then $3x^2 - 3x + 1=3y^2+3y+1$, and $x^3-3x^2+4x-2=y^3+y$. Hence
$$I=\int_0^2(3x^2-3x+1)\cos(x^3-3x^2+4x-2)\,dx=\int_{-1}^1(3y^2+3y+1)\cos(y^3+y)\,dy.$$
Since $\frac{d}{dy}(y^3+y)=3y^2+1$, we have
$$\int_{-1}^1(3y^2+1)\cos(y^3+y)\,dy=\sin(y^3+y)\Big|_{-1}^1=2\sin 2.$$
Since $3y\cos(y^3+y)$ is an odd function in $y$, we have
$$\int_{-1}^13y\cos(y^3+y)\,dy=0.$$
Therefore, $I=2\sin 2.$

Comment: Beautiful approach! What motivated $y=x-1$?

Comment: @user265131 Thanks! OP has found that $x^3-3x^2+4x-2=(x-1)(x^2-2x+2)=(x-1)^3+(x-1)$; also, the integration interval is $[0,2]$, whose midpoint is $1$. So, I believed that the substitution $y=x-1$ and some arguments using symmetry will help us to find the answer.